# sudo command in terminal freeze for a couple of seconds

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Recently have my Ubuntu server begun to "think" (2-5seconds) when I'm entering an command that normally would be executed within milliseconds

if I for example starts `sudo nano`, it delays 2-3 seconds, BUT! if I quit and start 'sudo nano' again, it will start instantaneous (now closed)
..I'll wait 10-15 seconds, and now it takes 2-3 seconds to start again..

a similar situation (**behavior, not cause**) occurs when the  system can't resolve my host `sudo: unable to resolve host mysite.org: Temporary failure in name resolution` (this can take minutes)

but the current issue isn't saying anything, but I suspect the system is waiting on something, but I can't determinate what?

Anyone ever struck upon this issue, or anybody knows what to check?

update: appears to be doing something with sudo

```
14:47 /aman@proxy:~ time sudo chown aman:aman /localscripts/

real    0m5.499s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.009s
```

Answer (score 0):

rDNS broken? That is, when IP address x.x.x.x tries to contact it, the server will perform an rDNS lookup and not return until either a response or a timeout.

And looking at `unable to resolve host mysite.org`, I would say your DNS system on the server is borked.

Comment: the `unable to resolve host mysite.org` is because the VPN isn't working (turned off), but why should Ubuntu need rDNS when I'm starting nano ? or a shell script?

Comment: Because I am assuming you have things remotely mounted. DNS times out etc.

Comment: i.c how can test it /fix it?  maybe the system is trying the wrong interface/DNS first?

Comment: Login to server and run `dig` to see how quickly it can resolve local and remote IP addresses. You may have to run `rndc flush` first.

Comment: 25-50ms, but I've discovered that sudo is REALLY slow, I updated the main question with the result.